# My function could return a promise or value, how to avoid it?

Tags: node.js, promise, q

I think it's bad practice to have different return types. So, this is my function, and I want it to always return a promise.

I tried to simplify the scenario. Let's say I have two lines of products (line X and line Y) and the way I'm retrieving a product by name, from each line is totally different from the other.

Please also note that ideally, I wanted to have a function to "or" two promises and return whichever that resolves successfully. But I couldn't think of a better way to achieve this!

```
ProductService.findProductByName = function findProductByName(name) {
  return LineXService.findOneByName(name) // promise
    .then(function _returnProduct(product) {
      return product
        ? product // value
        : LineYService.findOneByName(name)); // promise
    })
};
```

Comment: wait... that results in always returning a promise. where's the question?

Comment: @KevinB `product` isn't a promise, but something returned by a promise.

Comment: Right, but it's being returned in a .then callback. the overall function is still returning a promise.

Comment: In general terms you can wrap it up in `resolve` but in this *particular* case it might not be relevant. That's a good note.

Comment: Thanks @tadman and KevinB! Interesting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that returning a consistent thing is better than an ambiguous result. Normally you can cast an arbitrary value into a promise easily enough. For example using [`resolve`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve):

```
if (product) {
  return Promise.resolve(product);
}

return LineYService.findOneByName(name);
```

It's worth noting, as Kevin B observes, that this is irrelevant in this particular case since your outer function always returns a promise. The need to promisify a value is only a concern if this is not part of a surrounding promise.